# Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, docker-swarm

- I have created a docker swarm and i have created two services such as drupal for web content and postgres for database purpose, and both the service i have attached with the same network.
- While in database configuration i have given my container name or service name in host filed.

`docker service create --name postgress --network my_net -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=akash postgres`

command for database

`docker service create --name my_web --network my_net -p 80:80 drupal`

command for drupal

If anybody know about the resolution **TIA**.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are trying to connect using host:port while you should use the container name if both services are in the same network

Comment: Yes, I have given the container as well but even tough getting the same error

Comment: @AKASH can you share the error ?